# angularjs - $resource cookie phpsessid changes every server request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, yii, angularjs-service

I use $resource to login to a (Yii) php backend. After the login I want to retreive all cars (for example). BUT the received cookie, contains a different PHPSESSID every request. How can this problem be fixed? (it works when I use a RESTclient (browser addon), but not in angularJs)

An usecase: (login + get all cars)

[LOGIN]:

`$var user = $resource(conf.HOST+'/user/login',{},{'login':{method:'POST',isArray: false}});    user.login({username:username,password:password}).$promise.then(function(resp,head){ // GOES WELL};`

**we should be authenticated now**

The server response cookie contains TWO received PHPSESSID's lets say **A & B**

[GET CARS]:

`var client = $resource(conf.HOST+'/api/client',{},{'all':{method:'GET',isArray:false}});
  var clients = client.all();`

The server response cookie contains ONE received PHPSESSID's lets say **C**
if i invoke the client.all() function again, the received PHPSESSID changes again to lets say D.

**How can this problem (changing sessionId over requests) be fixed?**

Comment: I am having the same problem with Zend Framework 2. 3 years still no answer.